# Robot Framework - TypeError: relativedelta only diffs datetime/date

Tags: python, robotframework

I get the TypeError: relativedelta only diffs datetime/date after execute code

This is my robot code:

```
Test calculate age
[Tags]   Test
${cal}      AgeTest   1988, 10, 1
```

This is my python code:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def AgeTest(dob):
age = relativedelta(date.today(), dob)
print (age)
return age.years, age.months, age.days
```

How to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datatype of **dob**  you're passing is `String` but in python is need `tuple` So you need to convert your string to `tuple`first,
Just Change following below

```
def AgeTest(dob):
    dobnew = tuple(map(int, dob.split(',')))
    age = relativedelta(date.today(), date(*dobnew))
    return age.years, age.months, age.days
```

Comment: So thank you it work now for return age.years, age.months, age.days but if I want it response "return age.years, age.months, age.week, age.days" why it incorrect count age.days like this ${cal} = (30, 3, 2, 20) days should return 6.

Comment: @SawitreeCha Hi the format is YYYY MM DD , and i got output (30, 3, 20). it's correct. What's output you got ?

Comment: I try to count it in week too by  use response "return age.years, age.months, age.week, age.days" and, I got output (30, 3, 2, 20) year, month, week are correct but day is not correct. The output should be (30, 3, 2, 6)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with Robot Framework, but it looks to me as it did not recognize your input as a proper date; looking at [docs](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html), possibly formatting it as `1988-10-1` could help. On the other hand, if `dob` is a tuple, you could make it to a `date` object easily:

```
age = relativedelta(date.today(), date(*dob))
```

Comment: You are right, "Arguments defined in Robot Framework test data are, by default, passed to keywords as Unicode strings." [Argument types](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#argument-types) So every arguments are passed as a string and not as datetime/date here. Also your suggestion is fine as well, but only from RF version 3.1, here is the list of the [Supported conversions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#supported-conversions).

Comment: My RF is version 3.1.1 but when I passed the argument with 1988-10-1 the robot return error "TypeError: function takes at most 3 arguments (9 given)"